# bash + command working fine on linux shell but not from cron job

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I am trying to disable the swap on our Linux machines with cron job

first I want to explain the right approach for disabling swap on linux machines ( we have RHEL 7.x )

the process should be like this

1 `swapoff -a &`    ( in this example we used it as process )

2 comment the line with swap in `/etc/fstab` as:

3 `#/dev/mapper/vg_lab_swap swap swap defaults 0 0`

we create cron job with name - `swap_disable.cron`

and cron jon looks like this ( we set the cron job for every min just for testing )

```
* * * * *  root [[ ` swapon -s | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -ne 0 ]] && [[ `  ps -ef | grep  "swapoff -a" | grep -v grep | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -eq 0 ]] && ( swapoff -a & ) && sed -ie '/\/dev\/mapper\/vg_lab_swap/ s/^#*/#/' /etc/fstab
```

so after waiting more then one min we saw that `/etc/fstab` file not update and actually swap not disabled

so we set only the following line in the cron job to understand if something with our syntax is wrong

more swap_disable.cron

```
* * * * * root [[ ` swapon -s | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -ne 0 ]] && [[ `  ps -ef | grep  "swapoff -a" | grep -v grep | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -eq 0 ]] && echo why_line_not_works >/tmp/file.txt
```

explain:

`swapon -s | wc | awk '{print $1}'`  - verify if swap is disabled

`ps -ef | grep  "swapoff -a" | grep -v grep | wc | awk '{print $1}'` - verify if swapoff process already running

and unfortunately this above simple line also not works , and file `/tmp/file.tx`t not created

so what is wrong in my cron job?

why the line:

```
[[ ` swapon -s | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -ne 0 ]] && [[ `  ps -ef | grep  "swapoff -a" | grep -v grep | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -eq 0 ]] && echo why_line_not_works >/tmp/file.txt
```

is working fine on linux shell console but not from cron job?

example when we run it from sh

```
cron.d]# sh
sh-4.2#  [ ` swapon -s | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -ne 0 ] && [ `  ps -ef | grep  "swapoff -a" | grep -v grep | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -eq 0 ] && echo why
why
```

Comment: cron is probably using `sh`,  not `bash`, to execute its commands. `[[` is not `sh`.

Comment: (I'd move all that into a separate script and run it from cron instead of trying to inline it)

Comment: I preferred not created a separated script

Comment: also I changed the "[[" to "[" but doesn't help

Comment: I also recomment learning to use `$()` instead of archaic backticks. They're easier to read and they nest properly.

Comment: If you just want the number of lines, use `wc -l` instead of piping to `awk`.

Comment: Use `pgrep` instead of `ps | grep something | grep -v grep`

Comment: I also test this line --> * * * * * root [ $( swapon -s | wc | awk '{print $1}') -ne 0 ] && [  $( ps -ef | grep  "swapoff -a" | grep -v grep | wc | awk '{print $1}')  -eq 0 ] && echo why >/tmp/test.txt   , but still not help

Comment: also this one not works already test it in cron --> * * * * * root [ $( swapon -s | wc -l)  -ne 0 ] && [  $( ps -ef | grep  "swapoff -a" | grep -v grep | wc -l) -eq 0 ]

Comment: Don't put code in comments. If you have more details, edit them into the question. Then you'll be able to format them more readably. But these long one-liners are hard to read even if you format them. Why don't you want to use a script?

Comment: sorry i am apologize for that

Comment: The && in `( swapoff -a & ) && ...` does not make sense to me. What exit code are you testing? Since _swapoff_ is run in the background, you are mearly checkin  whether **starting** `swapoff` in the background worked.

Comment: Also why is this tagged _bash_? At least from that part of the code you posted, I don't see any bash being involved.

Comment: Finally, I would not put such complex commands literally into a crontab, but into a shell script, and run just the script from the crontab. This gives you much better control over debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you declare your SHELL and PATH in your crontab to not have to specify absolute paths for all the commands you are running.

Try the following under your cron.d file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

* * * * * root [[ ` swapon -s | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -ne 0 ]] && [[ `  ps -ef | grep  "swapoff -a" | grep -v grep | wc | awk '{print $1}' ` -eq 0 ]] && echo why_line_not_works >/tmp/file.txt
```